# Reaching devices on Subnets

Tags: networking

The following diagram will explain more easily my needs (rectangle are Routers ):
[image]

I have a main router `192.168.0.1` which is handles 3 subnets and PCs.
I need`192.168.1.1` (about 30 IP's )and `192.168.3.1` (10 IP's) to be separated ( traffic, maintainability).

I need that a PC under main router (for example - `192.168.0.101`) to reach end-devices `192.168.3.x`, `192.168.2.x`

How do I start ?

Routers in use:

[TP-Link Router](https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/wifi-router/archer-ax1800/)

[Edimax  Router](https://www.edimax.com/edimax/merchandise/merchandise_detail/data/edimax/au/wireless_routers_ac1200/br-6478ac/)

[Xiaomi  Router](https://xiaomi-mi.com/wifi-routers/xiaomi-mi-wifi-router-3-white/)

Comment: Hmm, a router sounds like a pretty good place to add some routes.

Comment: @BrandonXavier Can you be more specific ?

Comment: First, if you're asking for specific configuration guidance, that's going to be difficult without knowing what type of router you have.  Second, your descriptions and diagram are a little confusing.  For ex:  Assuming you're using /24 subnet masks, I see 3 subnets in the diagram, but "2 subnets and PCs" in the text.  Plus where is 192.168.1.x in the diagram? What are those 192.168.0.x addresses by each of the bottom row of blocks?  You might find more productive help with your question(s) by sitting down with somebody more experienced with network design and going over your plans with him/her

Comment: @BrandonXavier thank you for your response. A) Yes actually it is 3 ( didn't count the 192.168.0.1 router ). B) yes, it is /24. C) I didm't ask for a specific config per installed router, but aby guidance/ terminology to start look, more than "routes". C) `192.168.0.x` is the address of routers `192.168.2.1` and '192.168.3.1` ( if it was not clear - rectangle are router :) ) . Hope it is clearer now

Comment: And generally speaking, this site frowns upon questions like "How do I start?".  Specific questions like "I configured <this route> between <this subnet> and <that subnet> but it's not working, can somebody point out the problem?" tend to be favored. (personally, I don't mind either type - but that's just me)

Comment: @BrandonXavier See updated question

Comment: Alomg with the answer below, this might be helpful: https://www.tp-link.com/us/user-guides/archer-ax20&ax1800_v1/chapter-13-customize-your-network-settings#ug-sub-title-5  Beyond that, your question might be a bit beyond the scope of a Q&A site like this.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Your router 192.168.0.1 is responsible for routing this traffic since it is the common gateway between all of the subnets.

To route this traffic your router needs an IP in each of the respective subnets. Brandon Xavier is correct in saying this is device specific in how you can accomplish this.

The proper way to accomplish traffic segregation is through the use of VLans if your router supports this, you can then use your router to route the inter-vlan traffic.

VLAN 1 Router Interface = 192.168.0.1/24

VLAN 2 Router Interface = 192.168.2.1/24

VLAN 3 Router Interface = 192.168.3.1/24

All your devices should use the default gateway of their respective VLans.

Add routes to your router to route between the VLans accordingly.

Comment: Nicely said - my only other suggestion might be to clarify vlans and/vs. interfaces.

Comment: This gets into device specifics and really depends on the router in question.

This can be accomplished with multiple physical interfaces or a single interface interface utilzing port based VLan tagging also depending on switch support for trunking on the interface to the router.

To add more questions we also don't know the intended use case here and multiple physical interfaces would be better if traffic is expected in excess of the interface speed.

Comment: @user7749674 please see updates in my question

Answer (score 0):

@Guy.D
Thank you for the additional information, the setup makes a bit more sense now. You are still leaving out some details so I will make some assumptions about IP Addresses below.

TP-Link Router WAN IP = xx.xx.xx.xx (Doesn't matter for our purposes)

TP-Link Router LAN IP = 192.168.0.1 /24

Ensure devices behind this router have a default gateway of 192.168.0.1

Edimax BR6478AC Router WAN IP = 192.168.0.3 /24

Edimax BR6478AC Router LAN IP = 192.168.3.1 /24

Ensure devices behind this router have a default gateway of 192.168.3.1

Xianomi MiWifi R3 WAN IP = 192.168.0.2 /24

Xianomi MiWifi R3 LAN IP = 192.168.2.1 /24

Ensure devices behind this router have a default gateway of 192.168.2.1

To route the 192.168.2.0 / 24 Network

Create a route in the TP-Link Router 192.168.2.0 /24 Next Hop 192.168.0.2

Create a route in the Edimax BR6478AC Router to 192.168.2.0 / 24 Next Hop 192.168.0.2

To route the 192.168.3.0 / 24 Network

Create a route in the TP-Link Router 192.168.3.0 / 24 Next Hop 192.168.0.3

Create a route in the Xianomi MiWifi R3 Router 192.168.3.0 / 24 Next Hop 192.168.0.3

I am not familiar with all these devices however since you are utilizing them in this manner you will also need to create firewall rules to match and allow traffic assuming you are using the Wan/Lan side of these devices.

Keep in mind that the devices on 192.168.2.0 /24 and 192.168.3.0 /24 are double nat'd and while this does work you should try to avoid this scenario if possible as some applications have a hard time with this. I would imagine your throughput here wouldn't be great in some cases too.

The proper way to do this is to utilize a Layer 3 capable switch (all inter-vlan traffic never leaves the switch), the Layer 3 switch should hold the .1 of each network and a single router used for internet access.
Alternatively a Switch that supports VLan Tagging with a Router that does as well with a "Router on Stick" type setup where the singular router holds the .1 and inter-vlan traffic is always sent through the router.